# Unexpected trajectory after a collision

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-physics

I'm currently trying to develop an arkanoid-like game in Unity but I'm having a problem that I can't seem to be able to solve with a satisfying solution.

When the ball hits the edges of two adjacent bricks, it "reflects" the velocity in an unexpected way: the ball goes to the direction where it was coming from.

For information, I have a world space size of : 5.625x, and each brick has a size of 0.703125 for 8 bricks per line. Also, every bricks have the same Y size for the collider.

I tried increasing the x size of the collider to some reasonable extent (0.74x for example) to make sure there's no gap between two bricks but the problem still occurs sometimes.

Here is a very ugly picture illustrating what's happening (the green arrow being the expected trajectory): [image: unexpected collision]

Thanks in advance for your help!

**EDIT**: Here are the inspector informations regarding the ball and the bricks. Regarding the lines of bricks, it's basically eight game objects with a boxcollider2d and a kinematic rigidbody2d.

[image: BallInformations]
The ball material has a friction of 0 and a bounciness of 1.

[image: BrickInformations]

Comment: Great, now all we need is a [mcve].

Comment: did you set rigidbody to continous dynamic or how its called? if that doesnt help youll probably have to create/resize colliders so that they fit adjacent pieces at runtime. but maybe someone has a better idea?

Comment: I've updated the post with more informations. All the rigidbodies collision detection are discrete. The ball is dynamic and the bricks and kinematic. I'm going to try resizing the colliders at runtime!

Comment: I am not a fan of Unity's Physics Engine. I've also created a game similar to like this. A pong game. And the physics were problem. So i calculated them for my self. In simple; If ball is going (1,1) in vectors 2D, when hit top wall; ball will go (1,-1) in vectors 2D. You can make calculations like that.  A simple [image](https://docs.unity3d.com/StaticFiles/ScriptRefImages/Vec3ReflectDiagram.png) of what i am trying to say.